# Kinetic js Resize Images

Tags: html, resize, image-resizing, kineticjs

I am using this example in my site, http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/labs/html5-canvas-drag-and-drop-resize-and-invert-images/ , for resizing images.

But what happens in my case is that this value activeAnchor.attrs.x , for example, in Update() function returns 2400 and then  2400-2158  and then 2400-2158NaN and then 2400-2158NaNNaN  and so on. Instead of starting with just 240 and get the right position of the anchors.

Does anyone know what could be the problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you make a jsfiddle with your example?

Comment: the code is exactly the same as in the example. But i found a solution. In the AddAnchor function in the dragmove event, I added these lines of code, mX = stage.getMousePosition(e).x; mY = stage.getMousePosition(e).y; this.attrs.x = mX; this.attrs.y = mY; before calling update() and seems to work.